# Android Studio, во время дизайна xml документа, отображаются не все атрибуты виджета

Tags: java, android, атрибуты

Раньше такой проблемы не было, а щас вот почему-то стала появляться.

Я частенько использую панельку с атрибутами, но в какой-то момент после тестового запуска приложения на телефоне, эта панелька с атрибутами меняется и в ней становится меньше элементов. Можно вернуть всё на свои места, после того, как в настройках панельки я уберу галочку с "Floating Mode" и снова поставлю, но это неудобно...

Подскажите, как можно избавиться от такой особенности панельки?

[image: Полная панелька, которая мне нравится][image: Панелька, которая мне не нравится]

Comment: Внизу панельки нажмите на `View all attributes` или на такие же стрелочки вверху.

Comment: Это понятно. Но мне удобно чтобы эти атрибуты были на этой панельке. Их проблемнее искать во всех атрибутах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То, что изображено на ваших скриншотах, скорее какой то глюк, чем особенность поведения, которую можно исправить. Тем более, что мне ни разу не доводилось видеть подобное. Можно надеяться, что какие то обновления исправят это.

Насчет того, чтобы добавить в такую панель больше необходимых вам атрибутов и при этом постоянно не искать их в огромной портянке среди всех, можно поступить следующим образом:

Открыть список всех атрибутов, нажав на стрелки, направленные в разные стороны, пройти по списку и отметить нужные атрибуты, как избранные (клик на свободную зону левее названия атрибута, при этом там появится звездочка)

[image: scrn]

теперь эти избранные атрибуты будут доступны на сокращенной панели в разделе *Favorite Attributes*

[image: scrn]

Данные избранные параметры будут присутствовать для всех виджетов всех проектов.